# mongoose how to check if id exists in array but that id is nested inside an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a listed out 2 collections , in which one collection has a field named **Users** which has reference to **Features Collection Id's** ,

Here's the model for both of them :

```
Features collection model : 

var FeaturesSchema = new Schema({

  name : String,
  uniq_name : String,
  created_by:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  status:{
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  created_at:{
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Features', FeaturesSchema);

and in User collection i have this : 

 features : [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Features'
  }],
```

from postman i am trying to add features to any user and I am sending id's of features as array of id's so that i will store the id's in user collection for a document something like this manner :

user1 :

```
    features : Array 
              0 : ObjectId('123456')
              1 : ObjectId('234556')
```

Here's the Postman and API for adding features to existing user :

```
Postman sending req inside body with JSON : 

{
    "status":"add",
    "features":["63eccae68ad678d675f32b04" , "another_object_id" , ...],
    "email":"user_email_id"

}

API : 

exports.updateFeaturesList = function(req,res){
  if(req.user.role !== 'superAdmin'){
    return res.json({status:'failure',data:[],msg:getMessage(req.body.lang, 'you are not authorized to perform this action')});
  }
  if(!req.body.status || req.body.status == ''){
    return res.json({status:'failure',data:[],msg:getMessage(req.body.lang, 'Please provide status')});
  }
  if(!req.body.features || req.body.features.length == 0){
    return res.json({status:'failure',data:[],msg:getMessage(req.body.lang, 'Please provide required features to add / remove')});
  }
  if (!req.body.email || req.body.email == '') {
    return res.json({status:'failure',data:[],msg:getMessage(req.body.lang, 'Please provide email id')});
  }
  const umail = req.body.email.toLowerCase();

  if(req.body.status == 'add'){
    User.findOne({email:umail},function(err,userFound){
      if (err) return handleError(req,res, err);
      if(!userFound)  return res.json({status:"failure",data:[],msg:getMessage(req.body.lang, "User not found")});
      if(userFound){
        try{
          User.updateOne({email:umail} , {$push : {features : req.body.features}}).then((success) => {
            return res.json({status:'success',data:success,msg:getMessage(req.body.lang, 'Features Added Successfully')});
          })
        }catch(err){
          console.log('Error in adding features to admins  : ' , err);
          return handleError(req,res, err);
        }
      }
    })
  }

}
```

**The above code works if new feature is added to any user , but it is also adding feature with same id , how can i avoid that ?**

Any help is appreciated , thanks !

Comment: Please try `$addToSet` instead of `$push`

Comment: will addToSet also works if i send multiple id's from postman and 1 or 2 id's already exists in features array ? @hungtran273

Comment: Yes, it will. Give it a try

Comment: yeah it worked , also i have added unique : true in db model and few more restrictions and changes aswell , post as answer so that i can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$addToSet`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead of $push will prevent duplicate element in array while updating. The input can be a value or an array.